# Java - Printing 2D array like a table - with borders

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

So I need to print a 2D Array like a table, and I have the numbers right, I just can't grasp the concept of printing borders for the table.

Here's what I have

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

And I would like it like this, including four character spaces in each box (so it can accommodate numbers in the 1000s) and the numbers aligned right.

```
---------------------
|   0|   0|   0|   0|
---------------------
|   0|   0|   0|   0|
---------------------
|   0|   0|   0|   0|
---------------------
|   0|   0|   0|   0|
---------------------
```

I don't need any corner borders (for example, a +), only the vertical lines (|) and dashes (-)

How would this be possible?

My code to print my array right now is this:

```
int [][] gameboard = new int[4][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < gameboard[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(gameboard[i][j]);
            if(j < gameboard[i].length - 1) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: what does `print_board` do?

Comment: Oh crap, I'll remove that. it does nothing right now. I'm just playing around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little math and string manipulation:

```
int rows=4;
int cols=4;
int [][] gameboard = new int[rows][cols];
int cellSize = 4;
int rowLength = cols * cellSize + cols + 1;
final char[] array = new char[rowLength];
Arrays.fill(array, '-');
String rowDivider = new String(array);
for(int i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(rowDivider);
    for(int j = 0; j < gameboard[i].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.printf("|%"+cellSize+"d",gameboard[i][j]);
        if(j == (gameboard[i].length - 1)) System.out.println("|");
    }
}
System.out.println(rowDivider);
```

Play with the code yourself at http://ideone.com/PnfqS0

Comment: Perfect! Super simple. I was getting close but it was way longer and more complex than this! Thanks again!

Comment: Now it will.  It's just a matter of how far a leap you think the asker can make once you deal with details they were having issues with.  Added in some pseudo-constants to make it more flexible.  Seems to work.

Comment: Yeah, I think Apache Commons's "StringUtils" has something better, but I don't think IdeOne supports that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a simple task, actually integers may be longer than 4 digits. You might first want to determine the length of the longest one and use it to format the width.

Assuming the length is 4 then you could try something lie this:

```
public void print2DArray() {
    int [][] gameboard = new int[6][5];
    for(int i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i++)
    {
        printDashLine(gameboard[0].length);
        for(int j = 0; j < gameboard[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.printf("|%4d", gameboard[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println('|');
    }
    printDashLine(gameboard[0].length);
}

private void printDashLine(int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length*4+(length+1); i++) {
        System.out.print('-');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

To understand the `%4d` Take a look at [format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a much simpler solution but it seems to accomplish your goal.

```
int[][] gameboard = new int[4][4];

  for (int i = 0; i < gameboard.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (int j = 0; j < gameboard[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%6d", gameboard[i][j]);
            if (j < gameboard[i].length - 1) {
                System.out.print("| ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```